# Objective C UIView translates on rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation, translate-animation

I have a problem rotating my UIView on iOS. When I start the animation to rotate, my view always jumps to a new position and starts rotating there.

my transformations:

```
originalState = myRotatingView.transform;
startAnimation = CGAffineTransformRotate(originalState, degreesToRadians(-50));
forwardAnimation = CGAffineTransformRotate(originalState, degreesToRadians(50));
backwardAnimation = CGAffineTransformInvert(forwardAnimation);
```

my methods:

```
- (void) stopAnimation {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    myRotatingView.transform = originalState;
    } completion:nil];
    rotatingViewState = STOPPED;
}

- (void) startAnimation {
  CGAffineTransform transform;
  if (rotatingViewState == STOPPED) {
    rotatingViewState = FORWARD;
    transform = startAnimation;
  } else {
    if (rotatingViewState == BACKWARDS) {
      rotatingViewState = FORWARD;
      transform = backwardAnimation;
    } else {
      rotatingViewState = BACKWARDS;
      transform = forwardAnimation;
    }
  }
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    myRotatingView.transform = transform;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if(finished) {
        [self startAnimation];
    }
  }];
}
```

This is what it looks like: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UR_vYAjhprE

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 originalState = myRotatingView.transform;
 startAnimation = CGAffineTransformRotate(originalState, degreesToRadians(-50));
 forwardAnimation = CGAffineTransformRotate(startAnimation, degreesToRadians(50));
 backwardAnimation = CGAffineTransformRotate(forwardAnimation, degreesToRadians(-50));
```

and pass `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` as `options` argument to the `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion` method.

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't work. setting the forwardAnimation to transform from startAnimation just moves the animation back to the starting point. Besides, the UIView jumps right from the beginning, therefor there must be something wrong with my startAnimation.
Once the animation started, it works just fine without jumping around.

Comment: and you passed UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState as `options` argument of the method?

Comment: Maybe there is some change of the `transform` value of your view between settings of the startAnimation, forwardAnimation, backwardAnimation values and call of the `startAnimation` method.

Comment: at least not in my code. I add a videolink in my initial question which shows the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had to deactivate "Use Autolayout" in the File Inspector of my storyboard.
btw: This could be related to iOS 7 and XCode 5.